# installing CUDA-9.1

Tags: cuda

I'm installing CUDA on a machine. I have no problems following all of the guides on here(there are a lot of them), but they all end in the same place: follow the prompts from there. So I follow the prompts, it tells me that the install is still going on and needs a reboot, go back into the command line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> then run the run file again. So I do that and then it gives me an error:

```
It appears that an X server is running. Please exit X before installation. If you're sure that X is not running, but are getting this error, please delete any X lock files in /tmp.
```

How do I get this thing working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CUDA has been successfully installed. The issue was that some security settings on my motherboard were preventing ubuntu from accessing the security certificates for the Nvidia drivers. Disabling the security features allowed nvcc to communicate properly with the drivers.